# OpenCV imread() returns no image data on iOS

Tags: ios, opencv

I'm trying to use the OpenCV's `imread()` function to load a JPEG image in a `cv::Mat`, but it fails on iOS (the same code works on OS X). The returned matrix is allocated and valid, but empty (i.e. it contains no data).

Do the functions `imread()` and `imwrite()` work under iOS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works, at least when you're saving and loading to and from the Documents-Directory of your running app.

```
//Creating Path to Documents-Directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ocv%03d.BMP", picNum]];
const char* cPath = [filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];

const cv::string newPaths = (const cv::string)cPath;

//Save as Bitmap to Documents-Directory
cv::imwrite(newPaths, frame);
```

Comment: Really interesting! I need to try this out. Thanks.

Comment: @MathieuGodart feel free accept this answer instead, it is the better answer

Comment: @Hammer You're right. I wanted to test it, but I won't have time for now…

Comment: I don't suppose anybody has this working 5 years on?

Answer (score 6):

iOS defines its own file system and I do not believe that imread() and imwrite() interface with it.  You need to use native functionality to load and save the images but once you get a pointer to the image data you can wrap it in a cv::Mat and then process it in opencv.  It should not be difficult to write your own cv_imread(), cv_imwrite() functions for iOS.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I came to the same conclusion, but I wanted to be sure about that. Are you? I use the native iOS methods to load images, it works fine. But in this case, I was trying to share some OpenCV code among different platforms… hence the question. ;-)

Comment: I have tried to use them before on iOS and never got it to work.  I haven't ever looked at the inside of imread() or imwrite() so I can't say I'm **sure** that there is no way to make them work.  I would be shocked if they did though.  Hopefully someone can give you a more definite answer

Answer (score 3):

Try to change `Compress PNG Files - Packaging` Settings to `No`

1. Selected targets `Build Settings`
2. Search `png`
3. Change `Compress PNG Files` to `No`
4. Change `Remove Text Metadata From PNG Files` to `No`

Comment: This exactly fixed my problem! In my project, jpg file could be `imread()` but png. The png could be read after changing these settings.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me when loading images from the app bundle.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pattern" ofType:@"bmp"];
const char * cpath = [path cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
Mat img_object = imread( cpath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
```

I could only get it to work with bmps though, jpgs and pngs won't work for now in my app.

Comment: Thank you! You need really convert image to .bmp and then are able to read it using imread from the app bundle

Answer (score 1):

There's an native function for this.

```
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>

// t and m are UIImage* instances.
// transparentImage and maskImage are destination Mat.
// true/false is alpha condition.

UIImageToMat(t, transparentImage, true);
UIImageToMat(m, maskImage, true);
```